# webdriver is giving timeout error after opening IE start page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am moving from selenium 3 to 4 and trying to run my tests in edge-IE mode. After starting the IEDriver with

```
var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

the browser opens but then does not hand control back the the code for the next step, instead I get a time out error.

here is my code.

```
 var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            options.AttachToEdgeChrome = true;
            options.EdgeExecutablePath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe";
            //options.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";
            IWebDriver edgeIeMode = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

here is the error

Unhandled Exception, See screenshotOpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:63459/session/197d3eaa-361d-433e-b8b5-0b5d6acb1e7b/url timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.d__35.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your edge and webdriver versions are up to date. Typically this happens when a version mismatch can't connect to the browser. I'm not sure if edge uses an IEdriver.exe executable, but if it does, verify that version too.